# Textbox Validation Works according to dropdown value

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have a dropdown in which 3 options are available:

- 'Cancelled'
- 'Postponed'
- 'Other'

I want that if the user selects the 'Other' option then the Comment textbox is mandatory, otherwise the Comment textbox is not mandatory,

Here is my validation code in the View Model

```
[Required(ErrorMessage="Please Enter Comment")]
public string Comment { get; set; }
```

and here is my Dropdown and validation code in view

```
@Html.DropDownList("Reason", new List<SelectListItem>()
{
    new SelectListItem() { Text= "Event Cancelled", Value = "Cancelled" },
    new SelectListItem() { Text= "Event  PostPoned", Value = "PostPoned" },
    new SelectListItem() { Text= "Other", Value = "Other" }    
}, "--Select Cancellation Reason --", new { @class = "form-control"})
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Reason, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
```

How do I make the comment mandatory only when other is selected?

Comment: Consider using a [foolproof](http://foolproof.codeplex.com/) `RequiredIf` or similar conditional validation attribute (or you can write your own)

Comment: How i use RequiredIf on dropdown value ?

Comment: Read the docs - you apply it on the `Comment` property - `[RequiredIf("Reason", "Other")]` And do not generate you options in the view - that code belongs in the controller

Comment: Is there any another option using jquery to do that?without using conditional validation

Comment: Why? But if you want to write your own validation attributes and scripts to work with client side validation, refer [The Complete Guide To Validation In ASP.NET MVC 3 - Part 2](http://www.devtrends.co.uk/blog/the-complete-guide-to-validation-in-asp.net-mvc-3-part-2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a scope of doing this in your post method(If you want)

```
Public ActionResult AssumeThisAsYourPostMethod(YourModel modelObject)
{
  if(modelObject.Reason=="Other" && String.IsNullOrEmpty(modelObject.Comment) )
  {
    ModelState.AddModelError("Comment","Your Validation Message");
    return View("YourViewName");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery on change event and if the value of the select is 'Other' then add required property to comment box.

```
$("body").on('change', "#Reason", function () {
   var Reason= $(this).val().trim() ;
   if (Reason == 'Other')
    {
     $("input[name = Comment]").prop('required',true);
    } 
   });
```